# Java Collections: How to divide a sorted list into sub lists

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have a list (EG: `LinkedList<SomeObject>`that contains elements ordered by a certain attribute (EG: `SomeObject.someValue()`). This attribute can and usually does repeat often/it isn't unique, BUT is never null.

Is there a convenient way to divide this into multiple Lists, each list containing only its equal in cardinal order? Also, can this be done with only once iteration of the list? For example, the original list:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
```

The desired lists from this:

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2,
3, 3, 3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not too convenient, but:

- start a loop. Store the previous item, and compare it to the current.
- if the previous is different from the current (using `equals(..)`, and be careful with `null`), then create a new `List`, or use `list.subList(groupStart, currentIdx)`

Comment: +1, but if it was an array, a modified Binary Search (one that finds the last instance, instead of the first) would be better (for large amounts of data)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Apache CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) to do this, where "list" is the original list, and "value" is the current value of the objects you want to extract a sublist for:

```
Collection<SomeObject> selectedObjects = CollectionUtils
    .select(list,
            new Predicate() {
                boolean evaluate(Object input) {
                    return ((SomeObject) input).someValue().equals(value);    
                }
            });
```

This approach means using a well known and well tested library (which always is a good thing), but the downside is that you will loop through the list once for each sublist you need.

Comment: To apply this to the OP's stated problem, you need to wrap the code snippet with a loop to select the values.  The result is an `O(N**2)` solution that makes no use of the fact that the input list is sorted.  Ughh.

Comment: @Stephen C: true, and that was what I was trying to communicate in the last sentence. This is not a problem if the input list is relatively small. But if it grows large, another single-loop approach is better. I try to avoid pre-optimization (cause it's simply the root of evil).

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure there isn't a java API method for this. However you can write:

```
 // This assumes your list is sorted according to someValue()
 // SomeValueType is the type of SomeObject.someValue()
 public Map<SomeValueType, List<SomeObject>> partition(List<SomeObject> list) {
    Object currValue = null;
    HashMap<SomeValueType, LinkedList<SomeObject>> result = new HashMap<SomeValueType, LinkedList<SomeObject>>();
    LinkedList<SomeObject> currList = null;

    for (SomeObject obj : list) {
        if (!obj.someValue().equals(currValue()) {
            currValue = obj.someValue();
            currList = new LinkedList<SomeObject>();
            result.put(currValue, currList);
        }
        currList.add(obj);
    }
}
```

This will return you an `HashMap` of sublists, where the key is the `someValue` and the value is the partitioned list associated to it. Note, I didn't test this, so don't just copy the code.

EDIT: made this return hashmap instead of arraylist.

Comment: You should return Map instead of HashMap and require List instead of LinkedList. Any you missed a `>` in the return value.

Comment: Hashmap is necessary as output because it's easier to look up a whole list by the key. It has nothing to do with whether the input is sorted. If you really look at the code, I take advantage of the fact that it's sorted.

Answer (score 3):

If you would use Google [Guava-libaries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMultiset<Integer> ints = HashMultiset.create();
        ints.addAll(Lists.newArrayList(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3));
        System.out.println(ints);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1 x 3, 2 x 2, 3 x 3]
```

If you need to count how many elements of x you have use `ints.count(x);`, if you have value types you do not need to have more then just count.

Comment: Do you get 3 different lists using this?

Comment: It is a set of `Entry<Integer>` not `Integer`, and you get 3 different Entry's. You can get a set of `Entry<Integer>` by `ints.entrySet();`.

Answer (score 3):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), use [`Multimaps.index(Iterable<V>, Function<? super V, K>)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable%2C%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).

Answer (score 1):

This should work (untested, but I am pretty sure everything is ok, This also assumes that the contents of the list are sortable):

```
public static List[] getEquivalentSubLists( List parent )
{

    List cloneList = parent.clone();
    Collections.sort(cloneList);

    ArrayList<List> returnLists;
    int end;
    while (cloneList.size() > 0)
    {
        end = cloneList.lastIndexOf(cloneList.get(0));

        returnLists.add(cloneList.subList(0, end));
        cloneList.removeAll(cloneList.subList(0, end));
    }

    return returnList.toArray();
}
```